# Making WAR file in Grails

Tags: tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler

I used the war command in Grails for making war file, but I got the error:

```
Error Exception occurred trigger event [CreateWarStart]: C:\Users\MultiSite\grails-app\migrations does not exist.
```

The application is working pretty good under run-app command.

can anyone help me how to figure it out?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using the Database Migration Plugin then you should have, by default, a `migrations` directory. Grails 2.x install Database Migration Plugin out the box. You can remove it from BuildConfig.groovy or you can to create `migrations` directory.

Comment: could you expleain more? the exact procedure

Comment: I recomend you to use the database migration plugin http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/index.html

Comment: I have already installed that plugin. The error still exists :-(

Comment: run first grails dbm-generate-changelog changelog.groovy and then grails dbm-changelog-sync after all you can run grails war. I recommend you to read the manual.

Comment: Creating `migrations` was enough in my case. 10x