# Grails build war file fails with no indication as to why

Tags: grails

Trying to move from run-app(which works fine, no problems at all) to running on Tomcat. However when we run `grails test war` the `Building War File...` step fails.

Here is the console output, I'm not sure how to force it to tell me the problem with the build.

```
Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to test.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Compiling 33 GSP files for package [infogriz]..
| Compiling 5 GSP files for package [debug].
| Compiling 4 GSP files for package [databaseMigration]..
| Building WAR file.....
```

And the popup window opens up with `'grails test war' has encountered a problem. Problem executing: test war.` Real helpful.

The "Details" Button gives this as more detail.

```
Problem executing: test war --stacktrace --verbose
Command terminated with an error code (see details for output)
------System.out:-----------
Loading Grails 2.2.0
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to test.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 2 source files.....
| Compiling 33 GSP files for package [infogriz]..
| Compiling 5 GSP files for package [debug].
| Compiling 4 GSP files for package [databaseMigration]..
| Building WAR file.....
------System.err:-----------
```

Any ideas? I tried adding --stacktrace but it still doesn't tell me why it's failing.

Edit.

Running from the command line thanks to Ian's comment. The new error is:

`` `| Error Error executing script War: : c:\Users\me\git\infogriz\grails
-app\migrations does not exist. ``

Guess I'll be building that file after lunch?

Comment: "the popup window opens up" suggests you're running this in an IDE, do you get any more useful output if you run it from the command line instead?

Comment: Yes I am running this in the GGTS. I will try and run from the command line.

Comment: Try `grails test war --stacktrace --verbose` for more info

Comment: @BurtBeckwith See my updated question. Adding in verbose didn't help either.
Looks like I need to install Grails outside of the IDE before I can build it from the command line >.<

Comment: If you run `grails wrapper` once from within GGTS you can then use `grailsw` on the command line without a separate Grails installation and it will auto-download what it needs from the internet - `./grailsw test war --stacktrace --verbose`

Comment: @IanRoberts the `grails wrapper` ran fine. From the command line, now when i run `grails test war --stacktrace --verbose` it tells me it's missing 'server' JVM in the jre7 folder.

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941796/no-server-jvm-at

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making WAR file in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166694/making-war-file-in-grails)

Answer (score 6):

I had that error once and I fixed it by creating the migrations folder at the expected location...

You probably updated to a newer version of Grails recently or you used a Grails version which was newer than the configured Grails version in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version control for your project?

A similar error occurred for me when I had CVS configured to prune empty directories. I turned off this feature and the Grails build completed successfully.